# Running a batch file in the background until a time is reached

Tags: batch-file, background

I want to make a batch file run in the background until it has reached a specific time, and then start the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `&` after your command line that executes the batch.

For example, with a script.sh file :

```
script &
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4340058/3424763

Use the `Timeout` command with `/T` after it and put how many seconds of delay you want in the delay. Example: `timeout /T 3600 /nobreak`
the `/nobreak` makes it where someone cant bypass the delay.
the 3600 seconds is the delay time (1 hour)