# batch file if statement based on datestamp of file

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I need to branch a batch files execution based on the datestamp of a file. Basically, there is a file that must be generated once per day, any time that day is fine.

pseudo code

`if (last modified date stamp of c:\temp\file1.txt) equals (current date) then goto TaskSucceeded else goto TaskFailed
:TaskFailed
echo "Task Failed"
exit /B
:TaskSucceeded
echo "Task Succeeded"
exit /B`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This .bat waits for 1 min then checks the day, and then performs an action
I got it from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299392/how-do-i-create-a-batch-file-timer-to-execute-call-another-batch-throughout-th)

You can change the time to once every 24h and replace the `CALL` files with the ones you want to call

```
@ECHO OFF

:LOOP
ECHO Waiting for 1 minute...
PING -n 60 127.0.0.1>nul
IF %DATE:~0,3%==Mon CALL SomeOtherFile.cmd
IF %DATE:~0,3%==Tue CALL SomeOtherFile.cmd
IF %DATE:~0,3%==Wed CALL SomeOtherFile.cmd
IF %DATE:~0,3%==Thu CALL WootSomeOtherFile.cmd
IF %DATE:~0,3%==Fri CALL SomeOtherFile.cmd
IF %DATE:~0,3%==Sat ECHO Saturday...nothing to do.
IF %DATE:~0,3%==Sun ECHO Sunday...nothing to do.
GOTO LOOP
```

Read about the date function in .bat

Comment: I just noticed it took out some of my pseudo code. I actually need it to compare to TODAY in some (any) numerical date format. If filedate = today then do something, else do something else. if datestamp of file1 = todays date etc.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q36498808.txt"
FOR %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO ECHO %date%|FINDSTR /L "%%~ta" 2>NUL >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO failed) ELSE (ECHO succeeded)
SET "filename1=my.7z"
FOR %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO ECHO %date%|FINDSTR /L "%%~ta" 2>NUL >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO failed) ELSE (ECHO succeeded)
SET "filename1=missing.7z"
FOR %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO ECHO %date%|FINDSTR /L "%%~ta" 2>NUL >nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO failed) ELSE (ECHO succeeded)

GOTO :EOF
```

Since you've not shown us the format in which you display dates - the date in a `dir` listing or the date in `%date%` then the above is simply a suggestion.

I simply used convenient filenames for testing. The routine works for me.

The crux of the method is that if `%date%` is `Fri 08-04-2016` and the filetime is `08-04-2016 10:43am` then `findstr` will find a match as if either the date-string or the time-string is supplied by the `echo` then `findstr` will set errorlevel 0 and will set errorlevel 1 or 2 if the date-string doesn't match or the file is missing.

You would need to examine the precise minutae of your date displays to determine whether it is reliable in your situation.