# Stop WebSphere JVM within time limit?

Tags: shell, websphere, ksh, aix, websphere-7

I am wondering if we can stop a Single JVM within specific time limit. If it is not stopping within that time limit then kill the process from shell script.

If we are executing  ./stopServer.sh JVM_Name  - It will run till the jvm will not get stopped or till any error and exit.

What I am trying to do is :./stopServer.sh JVM_Name - If this do not stopped within 2 min(suppose), then kill the process (But How to figure out it is not stopped within 2 mins through shell script before the process go for killing). I can write the condition to kill . But not sure how to do checks if the JVM stopped within 2 mins or not so that we can go ahead to kill process.

Can anyone please suggest shell script code to identify if the jvm is stopped within specific time limit or not?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4340058/5934435

Comment: @Sampada that seems to have been a windows question, speaking aix here...

Comment: Oh yeah. You are right @Stefan. I am sure something similar can be found for aix too tough.

Comment: I think I'm quicker explaining it than searching for duplicates... but if you find some feel free to add it

Answer (score 0):

A JVM is a process and as such can be stopped with the kill command - `kill $processid` or more brutal `kill -9 $processid`

If you start the JVM from a script using something like `java ...` then I suggest putting a `&` at the end of that line and in the following line

```
processid=$!
```

which saves the id of the background process.
Then

```
sleep 120
```

will wait for 2 min.
Now you have two options - either just kill

```
kill $processid /dev/null 2>&1
```

or first check if the processid might (very unlikely) be reused by another process (or use some other way to check if your JVM has finished, maybe a file that indicates this from your java program) and then if it matches use the kill.

```
ps -ef|grep -w $processid |grep -w java > /dev/null
```

If it has returncode zero then continue with the kill

```
test $? -eq 0 && kill $processid
```

I usually would trust that the processid is either my JVM or not used at all

Comment: Nice suggestion. I will be reaching office in next 1 hour. Will defintely do a check .

Comment: I tried your suggestion . I got at one doubt. $! is capturing the pid after the command got executed . Suppose the pid captured from background is not available and the new process(orphans) left . How to tackel this situation.Is this good 

./stopServer.sh JVM &  > /somelocation ;
sleep 120;
PID=`ps -ef | grep $JVM| grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}'` ;
if [[ "" != "$PID" ]] then 
        kill -9 $PID
fi

Comment: hmm, from your websphere tag I had nearly anticipated that the thing that you start might not be the actual process that you would want to kill. so your stopServer.sh spawns a java and that does not terminate after 2 min? Maybe it has work to do while stopping? Have you checked IBM docs about that?

Comment: Not yet . I can write it in while loop but need to check .