# Copy a file every 10 seconds using a batch script - only once

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to find a way to run a batch script on Windows that backs up my project directory to our local network file share server.

Example of what I would usually run:

```
robocopy /mir "C:\PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH" "\\NETWORK_FOLDER_PATH"
```

But, every now and then, my IT admin approaches me about a massive copy operation that is slowing down the network.

As my projects folder grows over time, this becomes more of an annoyance. I try to run the script only while signing off later in the day to minimize the number of people affected in the office but, I was trying to come up with a better solution.

I've written a script that uses 7zip to create a 7zip archive and splits it into volumes of 250MB. So now I have a folder that just contains several smaller files and no folders to worry about. But, if I batch copy all of these to the server, I'm concerned I'm still running into the same problem.

So my initial idea was to run copy one file at a time every 5-10sec. rather than all at once. But I would only want the script to run once. I know I could write a loop and rely on robocopy's /mir tag to skip files that have already been backed up, but I don't want to have to monitor the script once I start it.

I want to run the script when I'm ready to do a backup and then have it copy the files up to the network at intervals to avoid over taxing our small network.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a batch file timer to execute / call another batch throughout the day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299392/how-do-i-create-a-batch-file-timer-to-execute-call-another-batch-throughout-th)

Comment: Most likely you want to use `version control` instead of copying project folders all over the place. Really. Really really.

Comment: why not use version control such as git?

Comment: Version control would be over kill in this case. These are projects that I alone work on, and after the project is finished, the files are deleted. I'm not talking source code, I do use version control for all of my web dev projects for work. But, in this case, I am simply referring to projects outside of dev that I also work on. Video editing, image editing, material files for architectural software I support, etc. many of us copy/backup to our own personal employee folder out on the network, but doing so in large quantities like this seems to slow things to a crawl.

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy has a special option to throttle data traffic while copying.

> `/ipg:n` - Specifies the inter-packet gap to free bandwidth on slow lines.

The number `n` is the number of milliseconds for Robocopy to wait after each block of 64 KB.
The higher the number, the slower Robocopy gets, but also: the less likely you will run into a conflict with your IT admin.

Example:

```
robocopy /mir /ipg:50 "C:\PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH" "\\NETWORK_FOLDER_PATH"
```

On a file of 1 GB (about 16,000 blocks of 64 KB each), this will increase the time it takes to copy the file with 800 seconds (16,000 x 50 ms).

Suppose it normally takes 80 seconds to copy this file; this might well be the case on a 100 Mbit connection.
Then the total time becomes 80 + 800 = 880 seconds (almost 15 minutes).
The bandwidth used is 8000 Mbit / 880 sec = 9.1 Mbit/s.
This leaves more than 90 Mbit/s of bandwidth for other processes to use.

Other options you may find useful:

> `/rh:hhmm-hhmm` - Specifies run times when new copies may be started.
>   `/pf` - Checks run times on a per-file (not per-pass) basis.

Source:

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx
- http://www.zeda.nl/index.php/en/copy-files-on-slow-links
- http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/robocopy-over-network